# Month/Year clock ingame stopping the rest of my game

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, clock

I am using Tkinter to make a RISK type game (sort of closer to Empire) and I am trying to make an ingame clock for troop reinforcement and money gain.

The problem is: When I run it, the while loop stops the rest of the game... How do I make a clock that isn't horribly complicated that will add onto variables.

My code for the clock is:

```
def timeclock(m,y):
    while m <= 12:
        time.sleep(30)
        m += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
    else:
        m = 1
        y += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
```

The clock.configure goes towards a label I made for the game, it obviously just refreshes the text.

Just so you know, I don't use a class for my app or .pack functions due to I recently started Tkinter and I learned it without using those. Though I understand classes like most all intermediate python programmers. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `after` method to make your clock, because `time.sleep` stops everything until it has finished.

Have a look at this example. It creates a label and a button, then runs `timeclock` after 100ms. The `timeclock` function configures the clock, then calls itself again 100ms later. This does not interrupt the Tkinter mainloop, which is why the button still works.

As long as you do not put your app in a class however, you will have to make m and y global to use them in the functions, unless you can extract them from the label text.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def timeclock():
    global m, y
    if m < 12:
        m += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
    else:
        m = 1
        y += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
    root.after(100, timeclock)

def reset():
    global m, y
    m = 0
    y = 0

root = tk.Tk()
clock = tk.Label(root, text='Clock')
clock.pack()
m = 0
y = 0
button = tk.Button(root, text='Reset clock', command=reset)
button.pack()
root.after(100, timeclock)
root.mainloop()
```

To avoid globals you could do something like in the following example. It gets the month and year by looking in the label.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import re

def timeclock():
    result = re.match('Month: (\d+), Year: (\d+)', clock['text'])
    m, y = int(result.group(1)), int(result.group(2))
    if m < 12:
        m += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
    else:
        m = 1
        y += 1
        clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
    root.after(100, timeclock)

def reset():
    m = 1
    y = 0
    clock.configure(text = "Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))

root = tk.Tk()
m = 1
y = 0
clock = tk.Label(root, text="Month: "+str(m)+", Year: "+str(y))
clock.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Reset clock', command=reset)
button.pack()
root.after(100, timeclock)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I am glad this site has people like you to help people like me out. Can't wait to finish my game now!

Comment: The code in the question checks every 30 seconds. Checking every 100ms is pointless. At the very least you shouldn't check more than once a second.  There's simply no point to have accuracy to 100ms.

Comment: Oh right, I made the time so short to quickly be able to see if everything worked the way I wanted too, with months and years having multiple digits and so on. Forgot to look at the timing in the question when posting. I do however get the feeling from the OP's comment that he has figured out how to change the time himself.

Comment: I changed it to 10 seconds per check since the code runs 10 seconds per month. No problem!